# 1 user accessing two community sites with different sobject permissions for each site

Tags: community, customer-community

For a single user with a "Customer Community" license, and access to two different community sites. Is it possible that this user has "Read" access to a specific object on **one** site and "Read/Write" to the same object on the **other** site?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The best you can do is use mechanisms that override standard permission checks.

An example is to add a custom permission checked in a screen flow embedded in the digital experience page that itself runs in system mode (and therefore bypasses permission checks).

The screen flow checks that the user has the custom permission and if they do allows presentation and/or editing of the relevant data in its screens as needed.